# insomnia bitbucket git configuration about authentication token

Tags: authentication, bitbucket, insomnia

Today, i had problem with **Insomnia** git configuration.

Insomniais programming tools for api documentation. and need to manage with git version controller.

so i created a new repository and unlike a github i cant configure it as you see in image below:

[image: created a new repository and unlike a github]

my problem is: how can i get **authentication token** from **bitbucket**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

at the bottom left corner of bitbucket click on your profile image and select personal settings

create app password

[image: bitbucket insomnia create new app password]

create new app password

[image: create new app password authentication token]

copy and paste this app password as authentication token in Insomniato push or commit

[image: app password as authentication token in Insomnia]

Good luck

Comment: @Daedalus thanks ,but i create temporary and then revoke that app key. ;)