# Insomnia new project error: could not expand on reference master

Tags: git, gitlab, bitbucket, insomnia

when i create new project with insomnia and commit and push it into my bitbucket everything is ok

when my teammate want to connect our openapi3 project cant.

the error is :

```
 could not expand on reference master
```

How to reproduce it:

- he create new project in insomnia
- then from git button configure our bitbucket to fetch : https://stackoverflow.com/a/62442943/308578
- after click on pull button this error occurred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of create new blank project you need to use Git Clone

[image: insomnia git error when clone in new pc]